# Is it faster to use n = len(s) instead of using len(s) directly?

Tags: python, variable-length

Often to save some time, I would like we to use n = len(s) in my local function.
I am curious about which call is faster or they are the same?

```
while i < len(s):
  # do something
```

vs

```
while i < n:
  # do something
```

There should not be too much difference, but using len(s), we need to reach s first, then call s.**length**. This is O(1) + O(1). But using n, it is O(1). I assume so.

Comment: You could use the `dis` module and look at the byte code. You could also use `timeit` to benchmark it. I would be surprised if it made much difference.

Comment: `O(1) + O(1)` is still `O(1)`. You should profile your code to see if repeated calls to `len(s)` incurs any significant overhead before worrying about caching the return value. Note that it would be *incorrect* to do so if the value of `s` changes in the loop.

Comment: The obvious implication is that `s` does not change within the loop.  Any run-time optimizations will make the two expressions equivalent.  However, the obvious (?) answer is that you're asking the wrong entities: **time** it each way with `timeit` and see whether one is faster than the other in your application.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil... unless this is the inner loop of a time critical process you should do what is most maintainable, not what is fastest... this is evidenced by the fact that **those two don't do the same thing**: one is sensitive to length changes in the block and the other is not.

Comment: @chepner, theortically they are the same, engineeringly they are different.

Comment: @Pythoner Big-Oh notation is "theoretically". If you aren't talking about algorithmic complexity, then don't talk about big-oh.

Comment: @chepner no offense, how do you think to express `O(1) + O(1)` like idea? I think this is a proper/reasonable expression.

Comment: It is certainly not proper if by proper you mean correct. To be precise and correct, you could say something to the effect of  "it has the same time complexity but a higher constant factor"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga too verbose if so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, here's some benchmarks:

```
s = np.random.rand(100)
n = 100
```

Above is setup.

```
%%timeit
50 < len(s)

86.3 ns ± 2.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Versus:

```
%%timeit
50 < n

36.8 ns ± 1.15 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

But then again, it's hard to imagine differences on ~60ns level would have affected speed. Unless you're calling `len(s)` millions of times.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You're right, it's updated, the original point still stands, though. Thanks.

Comment: I'm surprised that it doesn't change that much compared to the literal, though.

Answer (score 7):

it *has* to be faster.

- Using `n` you're looking in the variables (dictionaries) once.
- Using `len(s)` you're looking twice (`len` is also a function that we have to look for). Then you call the function.

That said if you do `while i < n:` most of the time you can get away with a classical `for i in range(len(s)):` loop since upper boundary doesn't change, and is evaluated once only at start in `range` (which may lead you to: *Why wouldn't I iterate directly on the elements or use `enumerate` ?*)

`while i < len(s)` allows to compare your index against a varying list. That's the whole point. If you fix the bound, it becomes less attractive.

In a `for` loop, it's easy to skip increments with `continue` (as easy as it is to forget to increment `i` and end up with an infinite `while` loop)